# R - Formatting data per month and facet wrapping per year

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am practicing with R and have hit a speedbump while trying to create a graph of airline passengers per month.

I want to show a separate monthly line graph for each year from 1949 to 1960 whereby data has been recorded. To do this I have used ggplot to create a line graph with the values per month. This works fine, however when I try to separate this by year using facet_wrap() and formatting the current `month` field: `facet_wrap(format(air$month[seq(1, length(air$month), 12)], "%Y"))`; it returns this:

[Graph returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBhqq.png)

I have also tried to format the facet by inputting my own sequence for the years: `rep(c(1949:1960), each = 12)`. This returns a different result which is better but still wrong:

[Second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf57l.png)

Here is my code:

```
air = data.frame(
  month = seq(as.Date("1949-01-01"), as.Date("1960-12-01"), by="months"),
  air = as.vector(AirPassengers)
)


ggplot(air, aes(x = month, y = air)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Passengers (in thousands)", title = "Total passengers per month, 1949 - 1960") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"), breaks = "12 month") +
  facet_wrap(format(air$month[seq(1, length(air$month), 12)], "%Y"))
#OR
  facet_wrap(rep(c(1949:1960), each = 12))
```

So how do I make an individual graph per year?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second try you were really close. The main problem with the data is that you are trying to make a facetted plot with different x-axis values (dates including the year). An easy solution to fix that would be to transform the data to a "common" x axis scale and then do the facetted plot. Here is the code that should output the desired plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

air %>%
  # Get the year value to use it for the facetted plot
  mutate(year = year(month),
         # Get the month-day dates and set all dates with a dummy year (2021 in this case)
         # This will get all your dates in a common x axis scale
         month_day = as_date(paste(2021,month(month),day(month), sep = "-"))) %>%
  # Do the same plot, just change the x variable to month_day
  ggplot(aes(x = month_day, 
             y = air)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Month", 
       y = "Passengers (in thousands)", 
       title = "Total passengers per month, 1949 - 1960") +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, 
              se = F) + 
  geom_line() +
  # Set the breaks to 1 month
  scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%b"), 
               breaks = "1 month") +
  # Use the year variable to do the facetted plot
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  # You could set the x axis in an 90° angle to get a cleaner plot
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,
                                   vjust = 0.5,
                                   hjust = 1))
```

[image: Plot facet by year]

Comment: Amazing, worked perfectly! thank you.
One question: when mutating, why do you add `year = year(month)`? It doesn't seem to change anything about the data frame to my untrained eye. Thanks!

Comment: `year` is a function from the `lubridate` package that gets the year of a date (in this case, that is the column named "month"). So the line `year = year(month)` is actually creating a new column called "year" that contains the year of your date column.