# Plot time series data from multiple years together

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have data that is collected annually that I am trying to plot together.
For each year, data is available for some random subset of days.
For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

set.seed(123)
year1 <- seq(ymd("2019-03-01"), ymd("2019-10-31"), by = "day")
year2 <- seq(ymd("2020-07-01"), ymd("2020-10-31"), by = "day")
year3 <- seq(ymd("2021-03-01"), ymd("2021-10-31"), by = "day")

dat <- tibble(date = sort(c(sample(year1, 50),
                            sample(year2, 50),
                            sample(year3, 50))),
              value = runif(150)) |> 
  mutate(year = year(date))

dat
#> # A tibble: 150 × 3
#>    date       value  year
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2019-03-07 0.265  2019
#>  2 2019-03-14 0.565  2019
#>  3 2019-03-23 0.913  2019
#>  4 2019-03-26 0.902  2019
#>  5 2019-04-01 0.274  2019
#>  6 2019-04-12 0.321  2019
#>  7 2019-04-19 0.986  2019
#>  8 2019-04-22 0.620  2019
#>  9 2019-05-11 0.937  2019
#> 10 2019-05-13 0.467  2019
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

I want to plot the lines such that the x-axis represents 1 year, and there is a separate line for each year.
If I just put the date on the x-axis, each year shows up sequentially, as we would expect, but there are basically 3 years on the x-axis.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

I have tried to use facets as a work around.
This one has a similar problem of have three years on the x-axis.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

I can free the scales, but then the axes don’t line up, so it’s hard to compare across years.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

To illustrate what I’m looking for, I can force all dates to have the year `2020`.
This results in the plot I want, but it seems like there must be a better way than changing all of the dates?

```r
year(dat$date) <- 2020

ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%B")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Chicago             
#>  date     2021-08-03                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                            
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  backports     1.2.1      2020-12-09 [1] standard (@1.2.1)                 
#>  broom         0.7.9      2021-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  cellranger    1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] standard (@1.1.0)                 
#>  cli           3.0.1      2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  colorspace    2.0-2      2021-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  crayon        1.4.1      2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  curl          4.3.2      2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  DBI           1.1.1      2021-01-15 [1] standard (@1.1.1)                 
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1      2021-04-06 [1] standard (@2.1.1)                 
#>  digest        0.6.27     2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.7      2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] standard (@0.14)                  
#>  fansi         0.5.0      2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  farver        2.1.0      2021-02-28 [1] standard (@2.1.0)                 
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1      2021-01-27 [1] standard (@0.5.1)                 
#>  fs            1.5.0      2020-07-31 [1] standard (@1.5.0)                 
#>  generics      0.1.0      2020-10-31 [1] standard (@0.1.0)                 
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5.9000 2021-07-18 [1] Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@13c0730)
#>  glue          1.4.2      2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] standard (@0.3.0)                 
#>  haven         2.4.1      2021-04-23 [1] standard (@2.4.1)                 
#>  highr         0.9        2021-04-16 [1] standard (@0.9)                   
#>  hms           1.1.0      2021-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  htmltools     0.5.1.1    2021-01-22 [1] standard (@0.5.1.1)               
#>  httr          1.4.2      2020-07-20 [1] standard (@1.4.2)                 
#>  jsonlite      1.7.2      2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  knitr         1.33       2021-04-24 [1] standard (@1.33)                  
#>  labeling      0.4.2      2020-10-20 [1] standard (@0.4.2)                 
#>  lifecycle     1.0.0      2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  lubridate   * 1.7.10     2021-02-26 [1] standard (@1.7.10)                
#>  magrittr      2.0.1      2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  mime          0.11       2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  modelr        0.1.8      2020-05-19 [1] standard (@0.1.8)                 
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] standard (@0.5.0)                 
#>  pillar        1.6.1      2021-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] standard (@0.3.4)                 
#>  R6            2.5.0      2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  Rcpp          1.0.7      2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  readr       * 2.0.0      2021-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  readxl        1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] standard (@1.3.1)                 
#>  reprex        2.0.0      2021-04-02 [1] standard (@2.0.0)                 
#>  rlang         0.4.11     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  rmarkdown     2.9.5      2021-07-30 [1] Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@bc936f7)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13       2020-11-12 [1] standard (@0.13)                  
#>  rvest         1.0.1      2021-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] standard (@1.1.1)                 
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] standard (@1.1.1)                 
#>  stringi       1.7.3      2021-07-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  styler        1.5.1      2021-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  tibble      * 3.1.3      2021-07-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.3      2021-03-03 [1] standard (@1.1.3)                 
#>  tidyselect    1.1.1      2021-04-30 [1] standard (@1.1.1)                 
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1      2021-04-15 [1] standard (@1.3.1)                 
#>  tzdb          0.1.2      2021-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  utf8          1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  vctrs         0.3.8      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  withr         2.4.2      2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  xfun          0.24       2021-06-15 [1] standard (@0.24)                  
#>  xml2          1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                    
#>  yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] standard (@2.2.1)                 
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library
```

Comment: Answers to similar questions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377404/r-formatting-data-per-month-and-facet-wrapping-per-year) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974535/dates-with-month-and-day-in-time-series-plot-in-ggplot2-with-facet-for-years)) also involve changing to a common x axis scale by setting everything to the same year like you did.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is how to plot them over each other in the same panel then create the corresponding date in the same year, such as year 2000, and then plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

  ggplot(dat, aes(`year<-`(date, 2000), value, col = factor(year))) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "", col = "year")
```

[image: screenshot]